# Using lambda function in generator expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I am trying to count the total number of occurrences of a given val in the list using a `lambda` function:

```
def countOccurrence(givenList, val):
    result = sum(1 for i in range(len(givenList)) if lambda i: givenList(i) == val)
    return result

givenList = [3, 4, 5, 8, 0, 3, 8, 5, 0, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2]
print(countOccurrence(givenList, 5))
```

But the returned result is `16`, which is nothing but the length of the list.

Comment: Your filter isn't actually invoking the lambda. All it's doing is retaining the current element if the lambda object is "truthy", which it always is, resulting in a count that's equal to the length of the list (`1` for each item). A lambda isn't required in the first place, but if you really want to use a lambda, use it in conjunction with the built-in `filter` as a predicate for retaining items.

Comment: What do you think `lambda` is doing in your expression? Why would you need a lambda expression there? I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding. `lambda` expressions simply create a function object, just like a function definition statement, except lamdba expressions are *expressions* and can be used in other places. However, where you are trying to use it makes no sense.  You *could* do something like `(1 for i in range(len(givenList)) if (lambda i: givenList[i] == val)(i))`but that is a pointlessness convoluted way of doing `(1 for i in range(len(givenList)) if givenList[i] == val)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to count the number of 5's in a list you should use the Counter. You get the numbers of all other elements as a bonus:

```
from collections import Counter
cntr = Counter(givenList)
#Counter({3: 4, 5: 3, 4: 2, 8: 2, 0: 2, 2: 2, 1: 1})
cntr[5]
# 3
```

Answer (score 7):

if you are trying to count the number of 5's in a list you should use the builtin

```
 my_list.count(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why use a lambda?

```
def countOccurrence(givenList, val):
    result = sum(1 for i in range(len(givenList)) if givenList[i] == val)
    return result

givenList = [3, 4, 5, 8, 0, 3, 8, 5, 0, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2]
print(countOccurrence(givenList, 5))
```

Comment: `True` evaluates to `1` in an int context, so you could actually just do `return sum(v == val for v in givenList)` instead of going through the extra filter step (and it's always easier to iterate over values than iterating by index from a range).  But as Joran pointed out, using the built-in `list.count()` is even easier!

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case in Python, the best way to do something its make use of its built-ins as much as possible because they've frequently been written in C. In this case that would be the `count()` method of sequence objects, `my_list.count(5)` as @Joran Beasley suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68521620/355230).

Regardless, for future reference the code below shows how to use a `lambda` function in a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) like you where trying to do. Note that the `lambda` function needs to be defined outside of the expression itself and also what its definition needs to (because what you had wasn't quite correct).

```
def countOccurrence(givenList, val):
    check_list = lambda i: givenList[i] == val
    return sum(1 for i in range(len(givenList)) if check_list(i))

givenList = [3, 4, 5, 8, 0, 3, 8, 5, 0, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2]
print(countOccurrence(givenList, 5))  # -> 3
```